# Finding the domain and range of $f(x)=\sqrt{\frac{2x}{3}+4}$

Tags: calculus

> Find the domain and range of the function:
>
> $$f(x)=\sqrt{\dfrac{2x}{3}+4}.$$

I think the domain is $\{x \mid x \geq 6\}$ but I am stuck on the range.

Answer (score 4):

$$f(x) = \sqrt{\frac23x + 4}$$

Now for this to be defined, the inner expression must $\gt0$. So,

$$\frac23x+4\ge0\implies \frac23x\ge-4\implies x\ge-6$$.

You wrote $x\ge6$ so I believe this was merely a typo on your part.

Now for the range, notice that let $t=\frac23x+4$. Now $t\ge0\quad\forall x\ge-6$

Therefore $\sqrt t\ge0$. Thus the range is $[0,\infty)$

To summarize, Domain:$[-6,\infty)$
Range:$[0,\infty)$